# Order number populates each time browser is Reloaded Django

Tags: django

I have a function the my django views to create order, and the order has order number that is tied to items.

Here is the views.py

```
def summary(request):    # Client View
    context = {}

    request_user = request.user
    all_items = Cart.objects.filter(client=request_user, ordered=False)
    print "ALL ITEM", all_items

    client = request.user
    # print "Client is ", client
    location=request.user.signup.country
    print "LOCATION ", location

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST != "":
            order_number = create_id()
            print "ORDER NUMBER", order_number
            # print "rp ", request.POST
            account_bank_name = request.POST['account_bank_name']
            print "account_bank_name ", account_bank_name
            amount_paid = request.POST['amount_paid']
            print "amount_paid " , amount_paid
            deposit_slip_number = request.POST['deposit_slip_number']
            print "deposit_slip_number ", deposit_slip_number
            payable = request.POST['payable']
            print "payable ", payable

            item, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(order_number=order_number, client=client, location=location, account_bank_name=account_bank_name, amount_paid=amount_paid, deposit_slip_number=deposit_slip_number, payable=payable)
            item.save()

        order = Order.objects.filter(order_number = order_number)
        print "ORDER", order
        all_items.update(ordered = True, order = order[0])
        my_order = Order.objects.filter(client=request_user).filter(order_number=order_number) #Populate client's Order to template

        tied_order = Cart.objects.filter(client=request_user, ordered=True, order=order)
        print "TIED ORDER", tied_order

        return render(request, "selly/summary.html", {'my_order': my_order, 'order': order, 'tied_order': tied_order, 'order_number': order_number})
```

Each time i reload the browser a new order number is created.

How can i make the order number fixed even when the browser is reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Always redirect after a successful POST, even if it's back to the same page.

```
item, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(order_number=order_number, client=client, location=location, account_bank_name=account_bank_name, amount_paid=amount_paid, deposit_slip_number=deposit_slip_number, payable=payable)
item.save()
return redirect('summary')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, this adds too much complexity to a simple problem. Create the order number when you save the order to the database with pre_save signals. [Django 1.9 signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/signals/)

So, add a pre_save signal with your create_id() code to your Order object. When you save an Order the pre_save is fired.